# Object detection with every pixel information OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Input and Output Images of my code are here.

[image: Reference Images]

I want output as complete object detection with every pixel. Here I get with some shadows as well as other background pixels and missing some object points.

So can anybody have idea how can I get complete object detection (foreground detection) with this input images (object image and background image)?

Below is the code I have tried.

```
cv::Mat ImgObject, ImgBck;
ImgObject = imread("Object.jpg");
ImgBck = imread("Background.jpg");

imwrite("ImgObject.jpg", ImgObject);
imwrite("ImgBck.jpg", ImgBck);

cv::Mat diffImage;
ImgBck = ImgBck + Scalar(-20, -20 - 20);/* decrease brightness of background 
  because of brightness changes after putting object */

cv::absdiff(ImgObject, ImgBck, diffImage);

float threshold = (float)50;
float dist = 0.0f;  

for (int j = 0; j < diffImage.rows; ++j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<diffImage.cols; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3b pix = diffImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i);

        dist = (pix[0] * pix[0] + pix[1] * pix[1] + pix[2] * pix[2]);
        dist = sqrt(dist);

        cv::Point3_<uchar>* pFinal = ImgObject.ptr<Point3_<uchar> >(j, i);

        if (dist <= threshold)
        {
            pFinal->x = 255;  // fill blue as background
            pFinal->y = 0;
            pFinal->z = 0;
        }           
    }
}

imwrite("Obj.jpg", ImgObject);

ImgObject.release();
ImgBck.release();
```

Comment: you can't. improve your lighting and background material... crap in = crap out

Comment: Can you document the code you have written thusfar?

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, I will improve the lighting and background material for sure but is there any better way in OpenCV that can give me better result than this if so then that can be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use direct light on the object(To reduce Shadow and Reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I need to say that this is not an object detection task, but a saliency detection or segmentation task.

Second, as @Kartik Maheshwari said, you are facing a lightning issue which is not a solved problem in Computer Vision.

As an alternative answer, take a look at [this](http://cs-people.bu.edu/jmzhang/fastmbd.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am little bit familiar with OpenCV. If i can get some code in OpenCV then that can be helpful to me.